# UpdatePanelAnimationExtender: No animation when certain button clicked

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a GridView inside an UpdatePanel that is populated when a search is performed on the page. When it is populated or the page changed, it performs a fade animation. There are other operations that I want to perform that update the UpdatePanel, but I don't want these to perform these fade animations. The closest I have found on the ASP forums is: http://forums.asp.net/p/1037038/1487096.aspx

The problem with the solution proposed in that thread is that there is no way to catch the Updated and Updating events to animate. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick,

Is it possbile to consider using JQuery to do the animations?  May give you more control on the elements than just the use of the UpdatePanelAnimationExtender.

http://jquery.com/

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects

Comment: Yup, we are actually using JQuery already. I was hoping that it was flexible enough to do it using the AE! Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add some code for this answer, since I managed to discover a good solution to this using code from different places. :) (some was pasted, some edited; the final version of this isn't tested, but you should be able to get the idea from it!)

```
var postbackElement; // Global to store the control that initiated the postback

// Using JQuery here
$(document).ready(function()
{
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequest);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);
});

function beginRequest(sender, args)
{
    postbackElement = args.get_postBackElement();

    // This method can be used to do animations in place of OnUpdating

    if(postbackElement.id == "YourControlId")
    {
      // or something like: if(id == "<%= YourControl.ClientID %>")

      // run your animation here
    }
}

function pageLoaded(sender, args)
{
    // This method can be used to do animations in place of OnUpdated

    // Also, the args variable holds a list of panels that are being updated;
    // I didn't use this though.

    // This condition is true on the first page load
    if (typeof(postbackElement) === "undefined")
    {
        return;
    }

    if(postbackElement.id == "YourControlId")
    {
      // run your animation here
    }
}
```

Comment: add_beginRequest and add_pageLoaded really helps alot